# How to set form field name in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a form class for login form.

```
class LoginForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username','text');
        $builder->add('password','password');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'login';
    }
}
```

This code generate form:

```
<form action="/app_dev.php/login_check" method="post">
    <div id="login"><input type="hidden" id="login__token" name="login[_token]" value="b7521243e04f79fb55c77c6ea8dc782578beab99" /><div><label for="login_username" class=" required">Username</label><input type="text" id="login_username" name="login[username]" required="required" /></div><div><label for="login_password" class=" required">Password</label><input type="password" id="login_password" name="login[password]" required="required" /></div></div>

    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

But symfony requires that the fields are the names: username and password.

In security.yml config:

```
   form_login:
        check_path: /login_check
        login_path: /login
        username_parameter: login[username]
        password_parameter: login[password]
```

But it does not work.

How to set their names to the fields, or how to specify what names to use for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

link that may help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html.

the problem may not be in the form.